# How to find difference between two dates in different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a difference between two **date** columns from different dataframes based on **customer ID** from the first **dataframe**. For example: I find **max date** from the first dataframe for all customers:

```
df.groupby('ID_')['MONTH'].max()

ID_
26      2020-11-01
27      2020-11-01
28      2020-11-01

              ...    
4236    2020-11-01
4237    2020-11-01
```

Second **dataframe** has also **ID** for customers and **date** column:

```
       ID_      PAYMENTDATE
0      26       2011-07-01
1      569      NaT
2      570      2004-05-01
... ... ...
5260  4236      2021-05-01
5261  9172      2021-07-01
```

Some **ID's** from the second dataframe doesn’t exist in first and I should avoid them.

How to create a new dataframe that contains the right difference between max date and date of payment in months for each customer ID from the first dataframe?

```
For example

    ID_  Difference in months
    26   111
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Prepare Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = {"ID_": [26,27,28, 4236, 4237],
       "Max_Date": ["2020-11-01", "2020-11-01", "2020-11-01", "2020-11-01", "2020-11-01"]}

data2 = {"ID_": [26, 569, 570, 4236, 9172],
       "PAYMENTDATE": ["2011-07-01", np.nan, "2004-05-01", "2021-05-01", "2021-07-01"]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df1["Max_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Max_Date"], format="%Y-%m-%d")

df2["PAYMENTDATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["PAYMENTDATE"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

**df1**

```
    ID_     Max_Date
0   26      2020-11-01
1   27      2020-11-01
2   28      2020-11-01
3   4236    2020-11-01
4   4237    2020-11-01
```

**df2**

```
    ID_     PAYMENTDATE
0   26      2011-07-01
1   569     NaT
2   570     2004-05-01
3   4236    2021-05-01
4   9172    2021-07-01
```

#### Data Manipulation

> Some ID's from the second dataframe doesn’t exist in first and I should avoid them.

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["ID_", "ID_"])
```

**result**

```
    ID_     Max_Date    PAYMENTDATE
0   26      2020-11-01  2011-07-01
1   4236    2020-11-01  2021-05-01
```

```
result["Difference_in_months"] = ((result.Max_Date - result.PAYMENTDATE)/np.timedelta64(1, 'M'))
result["Difference_in_months"] = result["Difference_in_months"].astype(int)
```

**result**

```
    ID_      Max_Date   PAYMENTDATE      Difference_in_months
0   26      2020-11-01  2011-07-01             112
1   4236    2020-11-01  2021-05-01             -5
```

```
new_df = result[["ID_", "Difference_in_months"]]

new_df
```

```
    ID_       Difference_in_months
0   26                112
1   4236              -5
```